# Makefile variable dependecy execution behaviour

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Sorry I'm newbie in makefiles, I've the following makefile

```
RESULTS_FILE := "benchmark_results"


all: $(RESULTS_FILE)
    @echo "all executed" 

$(RESULTS_FILE):
    touch ${RESULTS_FILE}

clean:
    rm -rf ${RESULTS_FILE}

rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
touch "benchmark_results"
all executed
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
touch "benchmark_results"
all executed
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
touch "benchmark_results"
all executed
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$
```

whenever I call make, it always executes the "touch" command to create a benchmark_results file however when I call again, it still executes the command even though the file exists.

when i replace the $(...) with actual file name it's okay, it creates once and doesn't execute second. only prints "all executed"

what am i missing here?

```
RESULTS_FILE := "benchmark_results"


all: benchmark_results
    @echo "all executed" 

benchmark_results:
    touch benchmark_results

clean:
    rm -rf ${RESULTS_FILE}
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
touch benchmark_results
all executed
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
all executed
rt7@rt7-laptop-vivo:~/Desktop$ make
all executed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because this:

```
RESULTS_FILE := "benchmark_results"

$(RESULTS_FILE):
        touch ${RESULTS_FILE}
```

doesn't tell make that you want a file named `benchmark_results`, which is what your recipe creates.  It tells make that you want a file named `"benchmark_results"`, and that's not what your recipe created.

Make doesn't care about quotes.  As far as make is concerned, quotes are just like any other character, an `a` or an `x` or whatever.

If you really did want your filename to contain quotes you need to except them from the shell; this will work:

```
RESULTS_FILE := "benchmark_results"

all: $(RESULTS_FILE)
        @echo "all executed" 

$(RESULTS_FILE):
        touch '${RESULTS_FILE}'

clean:
        rm -rf '${RESULTS_FILE}'
```

But, you most likely didn't want the quotes in which case you should not include them in the makefile variable used to create the target and prerequisite:

```
RESULTS_FILE := benchmark_results

all: $(RESULTS_FILE)
        @echo "all executed" 

$(RESULTS_FILE):
        touch '${RESULTS_FILE}'

clean:
        rm -rf '${RESULTS_FILE}'
```